# I want the homepage to open without the modal iframe loading

Tags: iframe, bootstrap-modal

The command below works but the main page is waiting for iframe to load opening for him takes a long time sometimes.
How can I get the iframe to load just by clicking the shortcut.

```html
 <li>                                    
 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#carlist">carlist </a> 
 </li>
 
 
 <div class="modal fade" id="carlist" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-toggle="modal3" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-fluid modal-notify modal-success" role="document">
                <!--Content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!--Header-->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <p class="heading lead">Car List</p>

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                                <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                                                            </button>
                    </div>

                    <!--Body-->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="text-center">
                                                     
                        </div>
                       
                        <iframe src="carlist.aspx" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a button. When onClick you try to open the iframe.
Is carlist.aspx part of your project?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the button. theme layout is distorted.
yes carlist.aspx is in the project.

Comment: This should have been a comment to the question, rather than submitted as an answer.